# Background jobs for Rubymotion

Tags: rubymotion

I am building an iOS app using Rubymotion.
I need to find a way to create and run "background jobs" (like Resque) in my app.
What I mean by that is that when the user for example add a new task, instead of sending it directly to the server I want to wait for when the Internet connection is good.

Is there a gem or a solution for this?

Thankful for all clues!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have something like background jobs, you can take a look at [NSQueueOperation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSOperation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Basically a NSQueueOperation is like a container containing NSOperation.

An NSOperation is a sort of a job. But there is no persistence. Thus, if a NSOperations is enqueued in a NSQueueOperation and if you restart your application, the NSQueueOperation will be empty.

But in your case, it might be a little overkill. Instead you should listen to the Reachability notifications. You can use either the [Apple's implemtation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) or [this one](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability)(More powerful). When you device goes online, get the list of your items which haven't been created/updated on your remote service. You can find them by looking for their id or any other flags which could be used to determine their state.

For instance if a record doesn't have any id yet, it means it hasn't been created on your remote service yet. In the same way, you can use an `updated(Boolean)` attribute to know if an object has to be updated on your remote service.

For each of them, make a HTTP call to your api, and once your request if finished, update your object to reflect the changes (set the id, remove your flags ect ...)

hope it helps